# How to get checkbox value from FormCollection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a checkbox and button:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="search-block">
        <input type="checkbox" name="showAll" id="showAll">Include completed
        <input type="submit" value="Apply"/>
    </div>
}
```

and second thing in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    var showAll = collection["showAll"];
    TempData["showAll"] = showAll;

    ... 
    something
    ...
}
```

It's actually working, BUT:

If checkboxes are not checked, I am receiving null (doesn't bother me much).

If checkboxes are checked, I am receiving "on" from `FormCollection`, and this is not what I need. I want to receive true or false.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can put a hidden field of the same name with value 'false' in your form. <input type=hidden name=showAll value=false/> then if they don't check the box the value posted up in the form will be false.If they do check it you'll get "on,false" but you can sort this out in your controller bool x = (collection["showAll"] == 'false')

Comment: Is this kind of joke?

Comment: nope - if you look in the background of how some of the frameworks deal with checkboxes, you'll find a hidden field doing this - it ensures something is posted to the server

Comment: No matter how I look an your words, I can't see any confirmation that you actually read the question.

Comment: You want your checkbox to post a true or false. To do this you need to put a value=True into the checkbox input tag. In order to get anything posted to the server when the checkbox is unchecked - you need to put a hidden field into your form with a value of "false".  This is what is happening in Tashar's answer below and why you get "true, false" in your form collection. You just need to look at the first element - collection["showAll"].Split(',')[0]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showAll" id="showAll">Include completed
```

Will Post a value of `"on"` or `"off"`.

**This WONT bind to a boolean**,

To receive a boolean value you can use HTML Helper Checkbox
Like

```
@Html.CheckBox("showAll")
<label for="showAll" style="display:inline">Include completed</label>
```

***Update:***

> If checked the html helper will post back `"true,false"` and if
>   unchecked as `"false"`

You can have this workaround as

```
bool MyBoolValue= Convert.ToBoolean(collection["showAll"].Split(',')[0]);
```

This is because the Html helpers class adds an extra `hidden` field to save the state of the checkbox

Comment: Then... how it supposed to look by using html helper? Could you write it please?

Comment: Well, I received true and false... but I received them as "true,false" when checkbox was checked. Is there a way to separate them?

Comment: At least I am receiving false when checkbox are mot checked. Already something:D

Comment: @OlegsJasjko edited and I will recommend you to use `@HTML.CheckboxFor` if u r bindig a model

Comment: The thing is, I am not using model at least on this page. Im not sure that I'd decided to use FormCollection If I had a model :D. Will try your answer. Thanks.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox"   ..>` will not post back "off" (unchecked checkboxes do not post back anything). Just change the method to `public ActionResult Index(bool showAll)` in conjunction with `@Html.CheckBox("showAll")`

Comment: @Tushar    In case of a list of checkboxes in which each checkbox has a specific name like item.name in a foreach loop, what should be in place on "showAll" in Convert.ToBoolean(collection["showAll"].Split(',')[0]); ???

Answer (score 6):

I have tried out with input tag and it works as shown below:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkRmb" name="chkRmb" /> Remember Me?
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default login-btn" />
</form>
```

In the controller, compare the string value and convert its to a boolean.

```
bool rmbMe = (formdata["chkRmb"] ?? "").Equals("on", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3):

So I gave this a shot and it seemed happy to take it, where collection is my FormCollection object:

```
if (collection.AllKeys.Contains("Inactive"))
{
     np.Inactive = false;
}
else
{
    np.Inactive = true;
}
```

Please be advised that the name of the targeted element is confusing - but this was the intended result I was seeking.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting this to work and this is the solution I came up with. I'm showing it with an html helper.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.showAll, new { @class = "form-control", Name = "showAll"})
```

This is where I kept falling down and the following works.

```
bool MyBoolValue= (collection["showAll"] ?? "").Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it solved this same issue for me. Thought I would share it in case others came upon this issue in the future.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    Boolean tempValue = collection["showAll"] != null ? true : false;
    TempData["showAll"] = tempValue;

    ... 
    something
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
bool MyBoolValue= collection["showAll"].Count > 1;
```

when 1 then false

when 2 then true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just to make @marcinJ solution a bit clearer, this code works: if (form["Checkbox"].Count > 1)
            {
                something = true;
            }
            else
            {
                 something = false;
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ajax

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="ckReseile" checked/>
```

Save your checkbox checked value and pass it into controller

```
 var ckReseile = document.getElementById("ckReseile");

    var data3 = new FormData();
    data3.append("IsReseile", ckReseile.checked);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Adopt/Tst",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data3,
        success: function (response) {

        }
    });
```

In your controller extract your value

```
public JsonResult Tst(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        bool MyBoolValue;
        if (formCollection["IsReseile"] == "true")
        {
             MyBoolValue =  true;
        }
        else
        {
             MyBoolValue =  false;
        }

        return Json(MyBoolValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```