# Checkbox value is incorrect in controller, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using mvc 5 to do a page and I want to submit a value of checkbox to my controller. 
I got this:

```
<input class="checkbox-custom" id="idX" type="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox-custom-label" for="idX">Label X</label>
```

But the value in controller isn't correct. It's always false. 
I search and I need to add a Hidden Field , but How can I do that? Because I have label with for pointing to my input (checkbox)

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Are you passing a model to the view, if so can you post that as well and the value of the model you are expecting to change?

Comment: Also post `form` code. You have just added a single checkbox.

Comment: Try to add an attribute name="name of parameter in action" to checkbox

Comment: your input doesn't have a name.

Comment: Answered a similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987105/how-to-get-checkbox-value-from-formcollection/28987375#28987375

Comment: Your input has neither a  `name` or `value` attribute so there is nothing to submit